# Android: Accessing assets folder sqlite database file with .sqlite extension

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How do you read data from the sqlite database file in the `res/assets/` folder with the `.sqlite` extension in my Android application?

Comment: Why did you place the .sqlite file in the assets folder instead of the /res/raw?

Comment: You will want to try [android sqlite asset helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). It makes it a piece of cake.

Answer (score 34):

Try this code:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context mycontext;

    //private String DB_PATH = mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "(datbasename).sqlite";//the extension may be .sqlite or .db
    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    /*private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                        + mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                        + "/databases/";*/

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
        this.mycontext=context;
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if (dbexist) {
            //System.out.println("Database exists");
            opendatabase(); 
        } else {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
            createdatabase();
        }
    }

    public void createdatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if(dbexist) {
            //System.out.println(" Database exists.");
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copydatabase();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }   

    private boolean checkdatabase() {
        //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
        boolean checkdb = false;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            checkdb = dbfile.exists();
        } catch(SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        }
        return checkdb;
    }

    private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/(packagename)/databases   /(datbasename).sqlite");

        // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0) {
            myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();
    }

    public void opendatabase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null) {
            myDataBase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: In actually coding this for production use mycontext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir rather than hard coding "/data/data/(packagename)". This is the offical way to get the application data directory.

Answer (score 7):

Place old database (old.db) in your asset folder. Type this inside onCreate() of your activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
....

//=======Code For copying Existing Database file to system folder for use====//
    // Copying Existing Database into system folder
        try {

            String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName()
                    + "/databases/data.db";

            File f = new File(destPath);
            if(!f.exists()){
            Log.v(TAG,"File Not Exist");
            InputStream in = getAssets().open("old.db");
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destPath);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("TAG","ioexeption");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DBManager dbManager =  new DBManager(this);
        Log.v(TAG,"Database is there with version: "+dbManager.getReadableDatabase().getVersion());
        String sql = "select * from prizes";


        SQLiteDatabase db = dbManager.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        Log.v(TAG,"Query Result:"+cursor);


        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        dbManager.close();

....

}
```

Now you have to make a DBManager Class which subclasses SQLiteOpenHelper . Insert the abstract method and constructor. Don't forget to type correct database name inside super() of dbHelper.

```
public class DBManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TAG = "DATABASES";

public DBManager(Context context) {
    super(context, "data.db", null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.v(TAG,"On create Called:"+db.getPath());
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
}
```

Now you can access database by instantiating DBManager.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbManager.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
...
```

Don't forget to close database or u will get a SQLiteDatabaseNotClosed Exception.

```
db.close();
dbManager.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Its important that in the tutorial, when you call the file, make sure you pass the application context `getApplicationContext()` such that you have access to the correct assets, otherwise you might get a FileNotFound Exception.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to try [android sqlite asset helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). It made opening a pre-existing db a piece of cake for me.

I literally had it working in about a half hour after spending 3 hours trying to do it all manually. Funny thing is, I thought I was doing the same thing the library did for me, but something was missing!

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your .sqlite database to .db inorder to fit to Android.

On your app's first launch after installation

```
SuperDatabase database=new SuperDatabase(getApplicationContext(),"foods.db", AssetDatabaseMode.COPY_TO_SYSTEM);
```

On subsequent launches

```
SuperDatabase database=new SuperDatabase(getApplicationContext(),"foods.db", AssetDatabaseMode.READ_FROM_DEVICE);
```

Simply fire SQL queries

```
database.sqlInject("INSERT INTO food VALUES('Banana','Vitamin A');");
```

Get results on Array in CSV, JSON, XML

```
ArrayList<String> rows=new ArrayList<String>();
rows=database.sqlEjectCSV("SELECT * FROM food;");
for (int i=0;i<rows.size();i++)
{
    //Do stuffs with each row
}
```

You need to include my library for this. Documentations here:
https://github.com/sangeethnandakumar/TestTube

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to create a new SQLite database then over ride and implement the onCreate() Method as shown in the tutorial.

But if you are using a SQLite database that is created by another external source and you are going to pull it down, then leave the onCreate() method empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can only read database from asset folder as the resources folders are read-only. If you need to do more operation like create, update,  delete you can do a tricks. Copy the database from assets folder to storage and then you can do anything you want.

Here is a quick example of [Working with Android Pre Built Database.](https://github.com/jakirseu/Android-Pre-Built-database)

There is a easy to use library too for accessing database from assets folder. You can check  Android SQLiteAssetHelper  (https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper).  Good luck!