# How to copy file from asset folder to .../database folder in android

Tags: android, sqlite, copy

'm using following code to copy sqlite file from asset folder to database folder. i found this example here  [find CommonsWare's answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605555/android-accessing-assets-folder-sqlite-database-file-with-sqlite-extension) 
But im getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/android_asset/pg558.sqlite (No such file or directory)

```
void copy() throws IOException {

    InputStream in =getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("pg558.sqlite");
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("data/data/com.mireader/databases/MIBOOK");

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check you pg558.sqlite file, I've tried you code and it worked for my file. I copied a xml file from assets/ to /mnt/sdcard/.

Answer (score 0):

To copy a file from assets folder to /databases folder:

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data.db";


private void copyDatabaseFromAssets() {
    try {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        OutputStream myOutput;
        int length;
        InputStream myInput;

        String DB_PATH = this.getDatabasePath(AppSettings.DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath();

        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        myInput = assetManager.open("databases/" + AppSettings.DATABASE_NAME);

        myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH);
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.close();
        myOutput.flush();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```