# Android: Preloaded Database to table layout view

Tags: android, database, sqlite, tablelayout, preload

Im stuck trying to figure out how to pull the information from my pre-populated database that is in my assets folder to display in a tablelayout view. If you know of any clear tutorials or if you know how to do it could you please help me out.

Example of what I mean:

Database example:

```
            Mountains      Valleys    Rivers      Oceans
```

Vermount           yes            no       yes           no

kentucky           no            yes       yes          no

South Dakota       yes            no        no            no

(In the app if I was to display a specific row then the tablelayout should appear like this)

TableLayout View

```
           South Dakota         <--(I know how to put the header)

      Mountains       yes
      Valleys          no
      Rivers           no
      Oceans           no
```

Comment: Are you confused about doing the layout, or the database operations?

Comment: In a way both, I know I need to use a cursor to pull information from the database but I dont know how to combine it with tablelayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar, but didn't need a cursor.  Here is what I ended up doing for my project.  It takes in a dialog that displays the infinite progress spinner.

```
private class AsyncPop extends AsyncTask<Dialog, Integer, ScrollView>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute( ScrollView result )
    {
        setContentView( result );
        super.onPostExecute( result );
    }

    @Override
    protected ScrollView doInBackground( Dialog... params )
    {
        Dialog d = params[0];

        Connection con = StaticDBHelper.getCon( TabActivityDetail.this.getParent() );
        Statement st = null;

        List<Timestamp> date = new ArrayList<Timestamp>();
        List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
        try
        {
            st = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "select activityDateTime, detailText from xfu_ActivityDetail order by activityDateTime desc";
            st.execute( sql );
            ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();

            while( rs.next() )
            {
                date.add( rs.getTimestamp( "activityDateTime" ) );
                text.add( rs.getString( "detailText" ) );
            }
            rs.close();

        }
        catch( SQLException e )
        {
            //Can't do a whole lot about it right now, should log
        }
        finally
        {
            if( null != st )
            {
                try
                {
                    st.close();
                }
                catch( SQLException e )
                {
                    //Just ignore it, should log
                }
            }
        }
        //Formatting
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams textBoxp1 = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( 130, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams textBoxp2 = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
        TableRow.LayoutParams rowp1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams( 130, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
        TableRow.LayoutParams rowp2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams( TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
        TableLayout.LayoutParams table1 = new TableLayout.LayoutParams( TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT );

        TableLayout tableView = new TableLayout( _context );
        tableView.setLayoutParams( table1 );
        if( date.size() == 0 )
        {
            TextView dateView = new TextView( _context );
            dateView.setText( "No activity details availible for given filter" );
            dateView.setTypeface( Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD );

            TableRow row = new TableRow( _context );
            row.setLayoutParams( new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );
            row.addView( dateView );
            tableView.addView( row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ) );
        }
        else
        {
            for( int index = -1; index < date.size(); index++ )
            {
                TableRow row = new TableRow( _context );
                TextView dateView = new TextView( _context );
                TextView textView = new TextView( _context );

                if( index == -1 )
                {
                    dateView.setText( "Date / Time" );
                    textView.setText( "Detail Text" );
                    dateView.setTypeface( Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD );
                    textView.setTypeface( Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD );
                }
                else
                {
                    dateView.setText( LoaderV5._fm.format( date.get( index ) ) );
                    textView.setText( text.get( index ) );
                }
                dateView.setLayoutParams( textBoxp1 );
                textView.setLayoutParams( textBoxp2 );

                row.setLayoutParams( rowp2 );
                row.addView( dateView, rowp1 );
                row.addView( textView, rowp2 );
                tableView.addView( row, table1 );
            }
        }
        //tableView.setColumnShrinkable( 1, true );

        HorizontalScrollView otherscroller = new HorizontalScrollView( _context );
        otherscroller.addView( tableView );

        ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView( _context );
        scroller.addView( otherscroller );
        scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled( true );

        d.dismiss();
        return scroller;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you want to add it in TableLayout?

```
Just fetch data from SQLite database and using custom adapter use ListView.
```

So **use Multicolumn ListView** to set all values in column type,

Look at [Multicolumn ListView in Android](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/)

[Android – Multi Column ListView](http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/tag/android-multi-column-listview-example/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to copy the Database file out from your assets folder to somewhere else before you can use it

This question has related content
[Android: Accessing assets folder sqlite database file with .sqlite extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605555/android-accessing-assets-folder-sqlite-database-file-with-sqlite-extension)