# How to retrieve data from database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Accessing assets folder sqlite database file with .sqlite extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605555/android-accessing-assets-folder-sqlite-database-file-with-sqlite-extension)

I have my own database file with name `abc.sqlite`. This database file has 4 tables(`diameter,diameterinch, diametermetric,products`). Now I pasted that file in assets folder. Now how i can retrieve the data from tables

Comment: Haven't you did google for this problem? Same as above question, there are plenty of questions available on the net.

Comment: Check this article: [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy that database to local memory or the sd-card and perform all function  **[Read Here](http://www.techin.info/2011/11/copy-database-from-assets-to-local.html)**