# no such table exception SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

My code is now as follows:

**Main app java:**

```
    String TAG = "DATABASES";    
    try {

        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName()
                + "/databases/data.db";

        File f = new File(destPath);
        if(!f.exists()){
            Log.v(TAG,"Dest DB doesn't exist");
            InputStream in = getAssets().open("airports.db");
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destPath);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG,"File exists: " + destPath);  

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(TAG,"ioexeption");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DBManager dbManager =  new DBManager(this);
    Log.v(TAG,"Database is there with version: "+dbManager.getReadableDatabase().getVersion());
    //String sql = "select * from airports where IATA='GRO' ";
    String sql = "select count(*) from airports";


    SQLiteDatabase db = dbManager.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    Log.v(TAG,"Query Result:"+cursor);


    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    dbManager.close();
```

**My DBManager.java:**

```
package com.jammo.mywidget4;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TAG = "DATABASES";

public DBManager(Context context) {
    super(context, "data.db", null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.v(TAG,"On create Called:"+db.getPath());
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
}
```

Now the execution runs ok in the main.java on initiation of "db", however fails on the next line where it tries to execute rawQuery()

FYI "select count(*) from airports" run on my Sqlite DB Manager GUI returns 1650 rows.

**Error log is saying :**

```
03-04 21:54:24.200: E/AndroidRuntime(11513): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 21:54:24.200: E/AndroidRuntime(11513): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jammo.mywidget4/com.jammo.mywidget4.SectorInfo}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: airports: , while compiling: select count(*) from airports
```

Local /assets/airports.db "seems" to be being detected and copied to /data/data/mypackage/databases/data.db as "file is found"

Many thanks
J

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android sqlite rowcount is always zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208954/android-sqlite-rowcount-is-always-zero)

Comment: Please edit your previous question instead of opening new ones

Comment: Sorry, I was advised in my last thread to open a new one, with new code and new error messages

Comment: @RaghavSood That is partially on me, this question is actually different than the other one. I told him to post it as a new one.

Comment: @Jammo Ah alright. Its alright then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without using your DBManager class.

Comment out this line...

```
DBManager dbManager =  new DBManager(this);
```

...then open the database explicitly by replacing this line...

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbManager.getReadableDatabase();
```

...with...

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(destPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

Then clear the app data so the database is re-copied from your `assets` directory.

**EDIT:** Even though my suggestion worked, it's actually just a workaround and the root of your problem was this...

```
String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/data.db";
```

You should avoid using hard-coded paths with Android - they may work fine for many devices but there is no guarantee they'll work with all devices or even with all versions of Android.

The problem was you were creating / copying your database to that path but the DBManager class was presumably creating an empty database located somewhere on a different path in the file-system.

To fix this for all devices and Android versions, before copying the database, I would use...

```
SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("data.db", null)
```

...to create a 'dummy' (empty) database. Then I'd call...

```
getDatabasePath("data.db")
```

...to get the absolute path to `data.db`. You can then overwrite that database during the copy operation and from then on you can use a class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and it will find the correct database.

Comment: Brilliant, this did the trick, thanks. I changed the condition  **if(!f.exists()){** to **if(!f.exists()||true){** temporarily to reflush everything over. Also removed the DBManager usage. I started getting a new error "table Android_metadata doesn't exist", so I added that with locale + us_EN and voila, all is working. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jammo : Glad I could help. See the edit to the end of my answer for an explanation and best-practice for Android paths.