# Reading sqlite file from asset folder

Tags: android

i am developing an application in which i want to read an `sqlite` database file from the asset folder of the project. i have searched the web but nothing found helpful. please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you really find nothing? Web is a waste man, lets smoke come'on!

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Read+sqlite+file+from+assets+android&oq=Read+sqlite+file+from+assets+android&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.5891j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=copy+sqlite+file+from+assets+android

Comment: Better to go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605555/android-accessing-assets-folder-sqlite-database-file-with-sqlite-extension

Answer (score 5):

Basically you can get an InputStream (from the AssetManager open function) for a file name and write it to an OutputStream.

```
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(fileName);
```

If you create your database using openOrCreateDatabase you might want to put the database in the databases folder...

```
    String fileName = "MySQLiteDB.db";
    File file = getDatabasePath(fileName );
    if (!file.exists()) {
        if (!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
            file.getParentFile().mkdir();
        }

        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];
        int numOfBytesToRead;
        while((numOfBytesToRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, numOfBytesToRead);
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(file, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can write :

```
val fileName = "your_file_name.db"
val file = getDatabasePath(fileName)

val data = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(file, null)
```

then you can use `rawQuery` to read any table from the data.