# How open readOnly database from assets

Tags: android, sqlite

I want opy some static info from database from assets (dont need copy on device).

How I can do it?

This code open database from inner folder:

```
public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: instead of the `DATABASE_NAME`, `(path to assets) + "\" + DATABASE_NAME`

Comment: и будет работать? Попробую. Как вы там?

Comment: "(dont need copy on device)" -- that is not possible. SQLite needs a local file on the filesystem. Either use `SQLiteAssetHelper` as suggested in the answer, or do not store a SQLite database in assets, but instead something else that you can parse yourself.

Comment: обязано работать) только там прийдеться путь к асетам скорее всего хардкодить, из системы у меня не получалось получить коректный путь. я в россию свалил)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), which has all the code that you need to install a pre-packaged database when your app is first run.

Ref : [Reading sqlite file from asset folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857734/reading-sqlite-file-from-asset-folder)