# ver 23.4.0 RecyclerView List not working correctly in Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My problem is that the RecyclerView list appears but starts somewhere in the middle of the list and displays just a single row at a time instead of multiple rows. I can scroll up to the first item in the list but I cannot scroll down. I have found some 'questions' on stackoverflow concerning RecyclerView usage in Android 4.3 but nobody seems to have a similar problem to me. With an earlier version of RecyclerView it worked fine. Using a Samsung Galaxy SIII.

I using the recyclerview in my app as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:name="na.com.company.myapp.List"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="na.com.company.myapp.List"
    tools:listitem="@layout/a_row"/>
```

Each row in the list is made up of the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/common_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/latin_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/common_name"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"/>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/select_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code within the AppCompatActivity derived class is as follows (in the onCreate function):

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list);
LinearLayoutManager linear_layout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linear_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
linear_layout.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linear_layout);
Drawable dividerDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.list_divider);
RecyclerView.ItemDecoration divider_decoration = new ListDivider(dividerDrawable);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(divider_decoration);
```

The app build.gradle file contains:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
```

The ViewHolder code:

```
public class TheViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener
{
    private View the_view = null;
    private CheckBox selected_item = null;

    public TheViewHolder(final View individual_view)
    {
        super(individual_view);
        the_view = individual_view;
        the_view.setOnClickListener(this);
        selected_item = (CheckBox)the_view.findViewById(R.id.select_box);
    }

    public void AttachCursor(final Cursor data_cursor, String[] columns, int[] views, boolean is_selected)
    {
        TextView a_view = (TextView) the_view.findViewById(views[0]);
        a_view.setText(data_cursor.getString(data_cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[0])));
        a_view = (TextView) the_view.findViewById(views[1]);
        a_view.setText(data_cursor.getString(data_cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[1])) + " " + data_cursor.getString(data_cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[2])));
        selected_item.setChecked(is_selected);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View clicked_view)
    {
        selected_item.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

and the Adapter (*query_cursor.getCount()* in the *getItemCount* function currently returns a value of 691):

```
public class SimpleCursorRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TheViewHolder>
{
    private Cursor query_cursor = null;
    private int layout_resource = 0;
    private String[] table_columns;
    private int[] layout_views;
    private View layout_view = null;
    private boolean checkbox_list[] = null;

    public SimpleCursorRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, int layout_id, Cursor data_cursor, String[] columns, int[] views)
    {
        layout_resource = layout_id;
        query_cursor = data_cursor;
        table_columns = columns;
        layout_views = views;
    }

    public Cursor get_item(final int position)
    {
        if (query_cursor != null && !query_cursor.isClosed())
        {
            query_cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        }

        return query_cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        int size = 0;
        if (query_cursor != null)
        {
            size = query_cursor.getCount();
            checkbox_list = new boolean[size];
        }
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TheViewHolder view_holder, int position)
    {
        Cursor current_cursor = get_item(position);
        view_holder.AttachCursor(current_cursor, table_columns, layout_views, checkbox_list[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public TheViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        if (layout_view == null)
        {
            layout_view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout_resource, parent, false);
        }
        return new TheViewHolder(layout_view);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post adapter and ViewHolder code

Comment: Are u getting any errors, please post your logcat also

Comment: I have a similar problem. Recyclerview is messed-up. So what I did was to revert the dependency into `23.1.1`

Comment: @ ajdeguzman. Are you using AndroidStudio? If you are how, how did you manage to revert the dependency? I cannot find anything via Google only how to upgrade.

Comment: @ zeus. Have added the adapter and ViewHolder code.

Comment: @ prat. The only error I get in the logcat concerns the loading of the database but in my app I have an assets folder containing the database which is then loaded (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857734/reading-sqlite-file-from-asset-folder[link])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lay with my code, in particular this method:

```
@Override
public TheViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    if (layout_view == null)
    {
        layout_view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout_resource, parent, false);
    }
    return new TheViewHolder(layout_view);
}
```

The list now appears is it should be when I rewrote the onCreateViewHolder as:

```
 @Override
 public TheViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
 {
    layout_view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout_resource, parent, false);
    return new TheViewHolder(layout_view);
}
```