# How to create a own searchView load from own databse?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, searchview

I'm having hard trouble to create a own searchView, load it from a database, and show the data into list.

Now my app is working, when I hit the search button appears a search list but I am not be able to do any search. When I start to write my search into a searhView the the app is not finding and filtering my list, also when I submmit the search my apps returns to the mainActivity showing my search list.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /** Database helper that will provide us access to the database */
    private MarluvasDbHelper myDbHelper;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myDbHelper = new MarluvasDbHelper(this);
        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ice) {
            throw new Error("Unable to connect");
        }
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();

        // Create and/or open a database to read from it
        //SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry.COLUMN_COD, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //displayDatabaseInfo();
    }

    private void displayDatabaseInfo(){
        // Create and/or open a database to read from it
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        // Define a projection that specifies which columns from the database
        // you will actually use after this query.
        String[] projection = {
                MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry._ID,
                MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry.COLUMN_MODELO,
                MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry.COLUMN_COR};

        // Perform a query on the pets table
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
                projection,            // The columns to return
                null,                  // The columns for the WHERE clause
                null,                  // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                  // Don't group the rows
                null,                  // Don't filter by row groups
                null);                   // The sort order

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, cursor, 0);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public Cursor getStudentListByKeyword(String search) {
        //Open connection to read only
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        // Define a projection that specifies which columns from the database
        // you will actually use after this query.
        String[] projection = {
                MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry._ID,
                MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry.COLUMN_MODELO,
                MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry.COLUMN_COR};

        //String whereClause = MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry.COLUMN_MODELO+ "=?";
        //String [] whereArgs = {"  LIKE  '%" +search + "%' "};

        // Perform a query on the pets table
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
                projection,            // The columns to return
                null,                  // The columns for the WHERE clause
                null,                  // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                  // Don't group the rows
                null,                  // Don't filter by row groups
                null);                   // The sort order



        ListView petListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, cursor, 0);

        petListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return cursor;
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the options menu from XML
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(search).getActionView();

        // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
               getStudentListByKeyword(s);

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                getStudentListByKeyword(s);

                return false;
            }

        });

        return true;

    }
}
```

CustomAdapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        // Find fields to populate in inflated template
        TextView modelo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.modelo);
        TextView cor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cor);

        // Extract properties from cursor
        String stringModelo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry.COLUMN_MODELO));
        String stringDescr = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry.COLUMN_COR));

        // Populate fields with extracted properties
        modelo.setText(stringModelo);
        cor.setText(stringDescr);


    }
}
```

How can I fix it? How to implement the setOnQueryTextListener method?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `What should I do?` ... you should show us a minimal representation of the problem.  You included way too much code.

Comment: The problem happens in this line code

Comment: cursor=queryPlace.getStudentList();

Comment: I added more details about my error

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I also cut off some code.

Comment: `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Cod (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  rowid as _id,Cod,Modelo,Cor FROM marluvas` <-- Please explain which part of this is confusing to you.

Comment: I would like to do this

Comment: // Define a projection that specifies which columns from the database
                // you will actually use after this query.
                String[] projection = {
                        MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry._ID,
                        MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry.COLUMN_COD,
                        MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry.COLUMN_MODELO,
                        MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry.COLUMN_COR};

Comment: // Perform a query on the pets table
                Cursor cursor = db.query(
                        MarluvasContract.MarluvasEntry.TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
                        projection,            // The columns to return
                        null,                  // The columns for the WHERE clause
                        null,                  // The values for the WHERE clause
                        null,                  // Don't group the rows
                        null,                  // by row groups
                        null);                   /

Comment: rowid as is confusing for me... I would like to get some data as in the projection and the cursor in comment in my QueryPlace, also when I use it my apps crashes

Comment: @takendarkk I added extra informations

Comment: @takendarkk I made some changes... Look at my question now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Reading sqlite file from asset folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857734/reading-sqlite-file-from-asset-folder)

Comment: I tried and I got error in this line code:  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); into a getStudentList

Comment: I will add table create code... I used contract and a code to read my database from asset folder

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you're trying to copy an existing database from an outside source to your device. Is that correct?

Comment: I have a database callled teste.db. I put this database into asset folder and I want to create a searchView to browser data from there

Comment: i see. From what I can tell, you're missing the statement that actually creates your table.

Comment: where? Ho can I fix it?

Comment: wait, I think I may have misread something. So, you are trying to access a pre-existing db.

Comment: I already read that info. My database was import from a excel and I need to be able to read the data from asset folder... I will work whit this data!

Comment: Yes! I'm t trying to access a pre-existing db

Comment: Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857734/reading-sqlite-file-from-asset-folder

Comment: I made some changes...Look above! Thanks!