# Query data from database in the asset folder

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've a database in the asset folder. How can I make connection or initialise the database to query data from the database

Comment: may help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605555/android-accessing-assets-folder-sqlite-database-file-with-sqlite-extension]

Comment: `Query data from database in the asset folder` **NO**. First, you have to copy it into the proper directory.