# unknown error (code 14): Could not open database. not working SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android, database

**Java Code**

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("file:///android_asset/dbCityCategory.db",null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    Cursor cursor=sqLiteDatabase.query("city",null,null,null,null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        arrayList.add(cursor.getString(1));
    }while (cursor.moveToNext());

    cursor.close();
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
```

**Exeption**

```
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
at com.eranewgames.autolike.Services.onCreate(Services.java:80)
```

What should I do to see Android Studio database?
What should I do to see Android Studio database?

---

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

     @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode==1){
            if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(MyCustomLib.ASSETS+"dbCityCategory.db",null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                sqLiteDatabase.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I added permissions, but the error I still get

Comment: check have you added write_external_storage permission

Comment: @MujammilAhamed, I,m update my question

Comment: check db file is present or not.http://stackoverflow.com/a/17846791/5515371

Comment: You cannot directly open files from assets folder. Instead, you need to copy the contents of your assets folder on an internal/external storage and later use the File path to open the file.

Comment: check  this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5949629/5515371

Comment: @MujammilAhamed, thx